# Issue with Keyboard controls in release - not occurring in unity editor

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm making a game that requires you to press the Enter key to start a game, i have set it up so that if the main menu object is detected a bool will be set to true which allows you to start the game upon pressing enter (deleting the menu gameobject)

```
  bool menushow = false;
  void Update () {

  if(GameObject.Find("Menu1 1(Clone)") | GameObject.Find("Menu1 1 (1)"))
    {
        menushow = true;
    }

    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Return))
    {
        if (menushow)
        {

            Destroy(menu1);
            GlobalVars.G_INGAME = true;
            GlobalVars.G_START = true;
        }
    }
```

I also have some code that pauses the game and opens menu1 when the user presses escape.

```
    if(Input.GetKeyDown("escape") && GlobalVars.G_START == true)
    {
        Instantiate(Menu_1, new Vector3(0, 0, -8), Quaternion.identity);
        if(GameObject.Find("Menu1 1(Clone)"))
        {
            GlobalVars.G_START = false;
        }                    
    }
```

G_START refers to the Pause/play state of the game and G_INGAME refers to if the user is in the middle of a game or has ended one (eg: died or just loaded in)

**MY DILEMMA IS:**
When i export the game and run the exe, upon pressing Enter to start the game, it begins, however i am no longer able to press escape to bring the menu back up. This does not occur in the unity editor however, where i can spam enter and escape and the menu will appear and be destroyed perfectly.

I would appreciate some insight on the matter as i am unsure as how to proceed when faced with a problem that does not occur in the unity editor which i am therefore unable to debug.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Can you check the [output_log.txt](https://answers.unity.com/questions/125049/is-there-any-way-to-view-the-console-in-a-build.html) you might have an exception somewhere. I also recommend using `tags` instead of finding objects by name.

Comment: You can find the the paths for files from this [link](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/LogFiles.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not how you should implement your menu within Unity. It is CPU intensive to create and destroy game objects, and it becomes difficult to track when you do on a recurring menu or object, especially as your project expands.

Instead, have a single Main Menu Game Object, named "Main Menu Canvas" and attach your canvas to that, then attach the following script:

```
...   // Standard Unity Namespaces can go here .  
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class MainMenuController : MonoBehaviour
{

private Canvas mainMenuCanvas;
private bool showMenu; // Set this to true if it should be implemented at game open

void Awake(){
  mainMenuCanvas = gameObject.GetComponent<Canvas>();
}

void Update(){
  if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Return))
  {
    mainMenuCanvas.enabled = false;
    GlobalVars.G_START = true;
  }

  if(Input.GeKeyDown(KeyCode.Escape))
  {
    mainMenuCanvas.enabled = true;
    GlobalVars.G_START = false;
  }

}
```

Comment: I'm using physical gameobjects with text mesh currently and raycasting to check for click, should i be using a canvas ?

Comment: @DylanRobertson Absolutely. It might take a wee bit of time for you to get it figured out, but trust someone who has developed numerous game in Unity - the canvas will ensure your UI is consistent, and well organised.

Comment: While i have you here could i get some clarification on Scaling ? whats the easiest way to just make everything shrink to fit the screen ? i don't mind black bars

Comment: @DylanRobertson Not to bang on about it, but the Canvas handles this. If you develop your UI to a sized reference e.g 1920 * 1080, then you can specify IF it should scale, and by height OR width as a priority. Then you can anchor your game objects to ensure they appear appropriate to other UI elements, regardless of the scale. There is no need for black bars, at all.

Comment: Is it possible to convert already made objects into canvas with conserved scripts ? i have already made all my ui.

Comment: Are your current GameObject's that you're using, Sprites?

Comment: I believe so, here are some pics. http://prntscr.com/mujc4x ,  https://prnt.sc/mujbyn

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189589/discussion-between-cmprogram-and-dylan-robertson).